# Pivot table calculated Field from count of values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a pivot table, and in the values I have the count of some fields.

```
 Region |   Count of Actuals    |   Count of Budgets    |   Percentage of Actuals
 Asia   |   40                  |   80                  |   ???
```

I want to add a calculated field to the pivot table "Percentage of Actuals" The formula should be [Count of Actuals]/[Count of Budgets]

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a calculated field in a Pivot table with a reference to a cell of the Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809490/add-a-calculated-field-in-a-pivot-table-with-a-reference-to-a-cell-of-the-pivot)

Answer (score 1):

The Regions are already being counted so there is no need to include "Count of" in the formula. I agree with @Andre that this might not really be what you want, but for what you ask just add a calculated field with Formula: `Actuals/Budgets`.

Select your PT so that PivotTable Tools appears at the top of your screen, Options > Tools - Formulas, Calculated Field..., add a sensible name (perhaps `%Act.`) in the Name: box and in Formula: put `=Actuals/Budgets`, OK.

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Excel 2016 and it looks like this is now under Analyze > Fields, Items, Sets > Calculated Field ... but I only have the baseline columns available and cannot put the count columns in the formula; is this something that has changed or is somewhere else?